# Hide keyboard when a search is submitted or a search suggestion is chosen

Tags: java, android, android-keypad, android-searchmanager

I have a action bar search widget that offers search suggestion too. When the user types in a query and submits it or chooses a search suggestion, the keyboard doesn't disappear. How can I resolve this issue?

I haven't been able to figure out how to hide the keyboard upon search submit or suggestion choose.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To hide the input method editor, use `InputMethodManager`:

```
  InputMethodManager imm=
      (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

You can use this from `onEditorAction()`, for example, as shown in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo).

Answer (score 2):

I have just face to the same problem, and this way to hide keyboard after search

```
  @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
   searchView.clearFocus();
 return true;
```

}

GoodLuck !!